# Do GraphDB Google Charts send my data anywhere besides my own server or client?

Tags: google-visualization, sparql, graphdb

After running a SPARQL query in the GraphDB workbench, one can make some nice [visualizations with Google Charts](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/querying-data.html) (in addition to an un-attributed "Pivot Table" tab.)

I have hospital records that are de-identified, but I still need to be as conservative as possible.

If I use either the Google Charts or Pivot Table tab offered in GraphDB, will the results of my query be sent to any computer besides my server and my client, in order to create the visualization?

If you don't know the definitive answer but can suggest a method for doing my own research, I would certainly try it on my own.  Maybe something with my browser's developer's tools?  I'm hoping to avoid using a packer sniffer application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that it is sending your data to some other server to render the chart or the pivot table. Google charts depends on .js being loaded (potentially from remote server), but rendering is done locally (client machine).

However, to make absolutely sure for yourself you can do the following on your server.

1. Load some test data (not your patient data, i.e. example data coming with graphdb) and draw something with Google charts. This is to ensure all .js libraries are loaded.
2. Disconnect from the network. Ensure both LAN and Wifi are disabled.
3. Now draw a different chart (to ensure cached chart is not re-displayed). If the chart can be drawn, it requires no external server to draw the chart.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this yesterday with my Windows laptop, but that particiular GraphDB build doesn't seem to have the Google charts functionality.  I'll try it in a VM or on my home Linux server toady.

Comment: Running GraphDB in an Ubuntu VirtualBox, with the network taken offline, it is still possible to create Google Charts of GraphDB SAPRQL results.  Thanks.